# VS2008: How do I make symbols defined in stdafx.h visible to the resource compiler?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, preprocessor, conditional-compilation

I am working on a VC++ project under VS2008. My resource files contain some pre-processor directives for conditional compilation. Some of the symbols controlling the conditional compilation are defined in `stdafx.h`. I need these symbols to be visible to the resource compiler as well. How do I make this happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Right-click the resource file in the resource view
- Select *Resource Includes...* from the context menu
- Insert `#include "headerfile.h"`

However, I think you should not include stdafx from there, but extract the symbols to a seperate header, so that the resouce compiler is not confused with whatever else you might have in stdafx.